# Accordion component hide on initial state with CSS + Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclicklistener, accordion

So i have been trying to build this accordion component for a review section for a couple of days...I'm really new to javascript and have figured it out mostly except the review section that collapses out is being shown in the initial state so on a page reload you see the section expanded right away, and only is hidden when you click the expand arrow. I would rather it be hidden on the initial state so it only is shown after the user clicks the expand arrow.

I have a div with the class="reviewsHide" as a wrapper and another div with the class="reviewsActive" as a wrapper. Its written in sass and any solution i try to come up with in targeting the wrapper with javascript doesn't apply its children class styles so it ends up not looking right. Inside the main container wrappers i have 3 more container sections each is its own container. with a couple of classes inside each of those containers.

```
                    <div class="reviewsHide">
                        <div class="reviewsActive">
                            <div class="reviewsActive__top">
                                <button href="#" class="reviewsActive__top-smallTxt">Write A Review &rarr;</button>
                                <span class="reviewsActive__top-largeTxt">Reviews(10)</span>
                                <button href="#" class="reviewsActive__top-smallTxt">More Reviews &rarr;</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="reviewsActive__bottomL">
                                <div class="reviewsActive__bottomL-title">
                                    <img class="starSmall"src="img/main/StarRating.svg" alt="Star Rating"> Title
                                </div>
                                <p class="reviewsActive__bottomL-reviewP">
                                    &nbsp Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis, dolorem quae! Quidem officiis rerum nam, veritatis ullam, placeat est doloremque exercitationem, a quis sequi tempora blanditiis eligendi consequuntur. Ipsam a hic eligendi? Facilis vero fugit omnis ducimus inventore ipsam libero ad expedita numquam, ullam delectus ratione modi, atque esse veritatis.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="reviewsActive__bottomR">
                                <div class="reviewsActive__bottomR-title">
                                    <img class="starSmall"src="img/main/StarRating.svg" alt="Star Rating"> Title 
                                </div>
                                <p class="reviewsActive__bottomR-reviewP">
                                    &nbsp Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis, dolorem quae! Quidem officiis rerum nam, veritatis ullam, placeat est doloremque exercitationem, a quis sequi tempora blanditiis eligendi consequuntur. 
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

.reviewsHide.show {
    height: 15rem;
    display: none;
}

.reviewsActive {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background-color: white;
    height: 22.5rem;
    font-family: 'Montserrat Alternates', sans-serif;

    &__top {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        align-items: center;
        height: 3rem;
        width: 100%;

        &-smallTxt {
            cursor: pointer;
            font-size: 1.05rem;
        }

        &-largeTxt {
            font-size: 2rem;
        }
    }

    &__bottomL {
        @include reviewsBottom;
        margin: auto 1rem .75rem 1rem;

        &-title {
            @include reviewsTitle;
        }

        &-reviewP {
            @include reviewsParagraph;
        }
    }

    &__bottomR {
        @include reviewsBottom;
        margin: 1rem 1rem .75rem auto;

        &-title {
            @include reviewsTitle;
        }

        &-reviewP {
            @include reviewsParagraph;
        }
    }
}

    // Get the button, and when the user clicks on it, execute myFunction
    document.querySelector(".span").onclick = function() {myFunction()};
    
    /* myFunction toggles between adding and removing the show class, which is used to hide and show the dropdown content */
    function myFunction() {
      document.querySelector(".reviewsHide").classList.toggle("show");

/* This selector below is for the arrow animation to rotate on click */
      document.querySelector(".span").classList.toggle("spanshow");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-wrote my javascript to this and its working as intended

```
const reviewsOpen = () => {
    var expandArrow = document.querySelector(".span");
    var hide = document.querySelector(".reviewsHide");

    expandArrow.addEventListener('click', () => {
        hide.classList.toggle("reviewsHide");
        expandArrow.classList.toggle("spanshow")
    });
}

reviewsOpen();
```